# A Particular Way of Erasing Ancilla Qubits

Tags: architecture, fault-tolerance

I am currently reading the paper *Topological Quantum Memory* by Dennis, Kitaev et. al. My main interest is to conceptually understand the idealized assumptions / requirements of a quantum computer architecture. One of these requirements is fast measurements (see page three of the paper). Here is an excerpt that I am having a hard time understanding:

> > Furthermore, if we can measure
> > qubits and perform quantum gates conditioned on
> > classical measurement outcomes, then we can erase
> > ancilla qubits by projecting onto the {|0$>$, |1$>$} basis
> > and flipping the qubit if the outcome is |1$>$.

**Question:** How does this erase the ancilla qubits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a great paper, enjoy reading it! In the context of this sentence, “erasure” means to forget the previous syndrome outcome. If we project onto the computational basis and flip the ancilla when we measured 1, we ensure that the ancilla will be in the 0 state at the start of the measurement round. Thus the previous syndrome measurement data was erased.

It may be worth asking why this is needed, and indeed some authors [have claimed](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41534-017-0039-x), based on simulations, that it’s perfectly fine to just keep the previous ancilla result, and in post processing XOR all pairs of measurement outcomes in time to get the parity. However, in practice this is not the case and they’re actually talking about it in this paper. Intuitively it’s because we need to pump entropy out of the circuit as the computation progresses, and more concretely, it helps us deal with accumulating errors such as ancilla leakage outside the computational subspace. For example, in the latest [google work on error correction](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-03588-y), they specifically showed the importance of ancilla reset to get to a constant error rate per round.

Lastly, there are more sophisticated and more optimal methods for performing this ancilla reset, if you are interested I can discuss this further.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, I am quite interested in learning more optimal methods for performing ancilla reset. Whenever you have time please kindly discuss this further.